# react-native-webview : For iOS text too small

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-webview

I have used `react-native-webview` for rendering HTML text. But text is too small in iOS while in android it is perfect.

Here are lines of code :

```
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";


render() {
  <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{ html: '<p>This is a static HTML source!</p>' }}
  />
}
```

Attaching screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57752837/webview-flutter-font-size-is-too-small-in-ios/57752878#57752878

Comment: Funny, my iOS fonts are great and my Droid fonts are HUGE!

Comment: @OneInaMillionApps did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<WebView
      originWhitelist={['*']}
      source={{ html: '<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></head><body><p>This is a static HTML source!</p></body></html>' }}
/>
```

link :https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/386

Comment: According my experiences HTML code should have valid DOCTYPE and html strcuture to render in web-view. If your content just "the body part", wrap it with html and body structure with DOCTYPE annotation to render correctly. Like `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></head><body>${yourHtml}</body></html>`

Comment: thank you this works and helped :-) also wrapping content body content around headers in the WebView prevents its modification within body :-)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the `<meta>` you can add `<style>` tag into the `<head>` section to scale the font:

```
<style>
    body { font-size: 120%; word-wrap: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works pretty fine to me,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1.00" maximum-scale="1.0">
      </head>
      <body>
        <p style='text-align:center;'>
           Hello World!
       </p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Works in both Android and IOS